# Timeout context manager should be used inside a task, nothing wrong to be seen

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiogram

So, I'm building a pretty sizeable bot and I've ran into a problem: for some reason in a very specific part of my code I just can't run a coroutine.

I am getting the error when I call `bot.send_message`.
I've already tried creating tasks, new threads, etc. I even tried using exec() with some global variables, but the result was the same.
I didn't think sending a message would be this much trouble. By the way, I can send a message without a problem elsewhere in my code (mainly I do that as responses to user messages).
I will be grateful if someone shows me the way out.

```
import nest_asyncio; nest_asyncio.apply()
from threading import Thread
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor
import asyncio


bot = Bot("bot token here")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


async def get_message():
    return "message"


async def resend_code(id: int):
    message = await get_message()
    await bot.send_message(id, message)


def polling():
    asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)


async def update():
    print("resend")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    try:
        await resend_code(1234567890)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)


async def main():
    Thread(target=loop.run_until_complete, args=(update(), )).start()
    Thread(target=polling, daemon=True).start()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    
    while True: pass
```

When resend_code is called, variable `message` does contain the desired dictionary, only bot.send_message fails.

Traceback:

```
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 267, in __step
    result = coro.send(None)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "bot.py", line 89, in resend_code
    await bot.send_message(id, message)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 346, in send_message
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_MESSAGE, payload)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 139, in make_request
    async with session.post(url, data=req, **kwargs) as response:
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1141, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 467, in _request
    with timer:
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py", line 701, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
```

**UPD**:
Added MRE

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you read the articles on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then use the _Edit_ function to modify your question accordingly. Right now, your code example is incomplete. There are undefined names there. Making a reproducible error example **minimal** does not mean you should omit parts that make it actually run. It should be one self-contained code snippet that can be copied and pasted verbatim to induce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a minimal reporducible example it is hard to tell anything about a fix, but there is one thing you are doing wrong:

`loop.create_task` was not designed to be called from another thread as you are doing, and it would eventually error out (can't be sure if your error is caused by this).

Anyway, the "feeder thread" that will create tasks to your existing event loop should call [`asynco.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) instead.This will make your `bot.update()` call as a regular call within your asyncio loop, and hopefully it is all you need to get going.

Comment: Thank you! This was the case, but not entirely: running `update()` threadsafe didn't fix my problem. However, making `polling()` a coroutine and running **it** threadsafe fixed everything.